# React Router reset state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

Task i want to prefill data in a Test Component

Consider a route with a component
Route path: /test
Component: Test

We are storing the prefill data in the redux state while loading the component in componentdidmount we will get the data from redux state and store in the react local component state. All components will be prefilled. after prefilling i will clear redux prefill data.

Issue: When i click the same route /test all state data are retaining. How to reset data when same route path.

Comment: You need to make sure that the `Test` component gets unmounted when changing routes. Local state will only get reset/cleared once the component unmounts.

Comment: When routing same route it directly calls componentdidupdate without calling unmounting. Is their anyway to reset state

Comment: Hmm, not sure if that's possible without some weird hack. What you can do is use `componentWillReceiveProps` and then use that to clear/reset state. Each time you route, the component will get new props from `react-router`.

Comment: react-router change in the sense of URL change. We dont want the URL change. is their any other way

Comment: Create a button in the `Test` component that resets state would work. It won't be automatic, but it can clear the state for you. What exactly is your use case?

Comment: Consider the route path: /testPath which has component Test. Test component fill the data using redux state. 
After prefill their will be a case. when user hits same url /testPath load the component without any prefill data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165593/discussion-between-rocket55-and-chase-deanda).